# Mdx Iif statment

Tags: mdx, pentaho, data-warehouse, mondrian, iif

I'm trying to get calculated measure while evaluating Pentaho Analyser.

**Point:** Need a measure with condition. My code:

```
IIf ([Product].CurrentMember Is [Product].[Food], [Unit Sales], 0)
```

So I get:

Drinks  0

Food    14

Else    0

End it works **only until** [Product] dimension is present on rows or columns.

But when I insert another slicer, and remove [Product] ( [Partner] for example) I get:

IBM   0

MS    0

Apple 0

**Instead of:**

IBM   7

MS    2

Apple 5

I know, the main problem is **CurrentMember** property, and it's always zero because there is on CurrentMember on given dimension. Please, do not answer with: 'Filter it on "Food"'
because I'm trying to build something more complex and this is a first step.

Is there any trick to get this Measure work?

**EDIT:**
I have 3 dimensions: Product, Partner, Country
I need to get via mdx formula calculated measure:
[Unit Sales] when it is [Product].[Food] and [Product].[Drink] and it NOT is [Country].[US] and [Country].[DE] but everything else.

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: Should that technically be when (Product is Food **or** Drink) and (Country is not US ** or DE)?

Comment: Yes.. Is there a solution?

Comment: I updated my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a specialist for Pentaho/Mondrian, but I would assume the issue is that in your second scenario, the `[Product].CurrentMember` is the all member of the products, not the `Food` member, and thus the system behaves as you told it, and returns 0.

From how I understand your question, something like

```
IIf(
    Count(
        Intersect(
            { [Product].CurrentMember },
            { [Product].[Food], [Product].[Drink], [Product].[All] }
        )
    ) = 1
    AND
    Count(
        Intersect(
            { [Country].CurrentMember },
            { [Country].[US], [Country].[DE], [Country].[All] }
        )
    ) = 0
    [Unit Sales],
    0
   )
```

should deliver what you want. The trick here is that the intersection between the one-element set containing the `CurrentMember` and another set can either have one element - in case the `CurrentMember` is contained in the set -, or zero elements - in case the element is not contained in the set.

Comment: Actually, I do not know how it works 'behind the door', as you said it's 'the [Product].CurrentMember is the all member of the products', but this does not work for me. Could you provide me another solution?
Thank you for helping!

Comment: @StevanPopov Could you please clarify what is meant by "this does not work for me"? Do you get an error message when using the above expression? Is there no error, but the result different from what you expect? If so, what exactly do you expect, and how does the result differ from that?

Comment: Sorry Frank, I really didn't explain my comment. It returns the same results as my formula in question - zeros.
My goal is to override SQL formula for value in ETL to get more scalability. 
My full question is how to get converted this:
SELECT
...
...
CASE WHEN valueOfDim1 IN (....) AND valueOfDim2 NOT IN (...) THEN sum(myValue) ELSE 0 END
...
...

If I need to ask another question, please tell me!

Comment: @FrankPI please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614680/mdx-calculated-measure-formula

Comment: @StevanPopov I have the impression I still do not understand clearly what is your requirement. What I understood so far: You want to define a measure `CalcUnitSales` as follows: If Product is used on rows or columns, the measure should only show the same value as the measure `Unit Sales` for the product `Food`, but zero for all other products (and presumably the value for Food as well as the sum across all products). If Product is not used on rows or columns nor in the slicer, the measure should be the same as `Unit Sales`. Please correct whatever detail is wrong with my understanding.

Comment: The measure should be the SAME weather I have [Product] on rows/columns or not. In both cases the same value. Thanks!

Comment: @StevanPopov And this same value should be the value of FOOD Unit Sales?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do it with tuple ([Measures].[Unit Sales],[Product].[Food]) because I need more complex things with more than filter.
Sorry, I'm really confusing, I edited question, please look.

Comment: @FrankPI
You helped me a LOT! You have also learned me much about how mdx formula woks. But your answer is giving me wrong result when there is NO [Product] dimension on ax. In that case it returns me sum without condition.

Comment: When there is no product on the axes, then the product CurrentMember is `[Product].[All]`. What should be the result then? How does this interact with the countries?